# File compression before upload on the client-side

Tags: javascript, flash, apache-flex, upload, compression

Basically I'll be working with large XML files (approx. 20 - 50 MB). These files needs to be uploaded on a server.

I know it isn't possible to touch the files with javascript, nor to implement HTTP compression on the client-side.

My question is that if any solution exists (flash / action script) that compresses a file and has a javascript API?

The scenario is this:

1. Trying to upload 50 MB XML file
2. Before upload a grab it with Javascript and send it to the compressor.
3. Upload the compressed file instead of the original one.

Comment: I found this but I never used it (and no Flash here): http://jszip.stuartk.co.uk/

Comment: Thanks for the link, but basically I would need a solution which works in all major browser such as IE7+, FF, Safari and Chrome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flash's inbuilt implementation of ByteArray has a method (`ByteArray::deflate` to deflate the contents (of the bytearray) The deflate algorithm is the [DEFLATE Compressed Data Format Specification version 1.3](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1951.txt).

There;s also a `ByteArray::compress` method which compresses using the [zlib](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1950.txt) algorithm

Hold on a bit, I'll write you some sample code to use this class and expose it to JavaScript.

**EDIT**

I've uploaded the file at http://www.filefactory.com/file/cf8a39c/n/demo5.zip

**EDIT 2** For those who couldn't download the files:

My ActionScript code in demo5.fla (compiled to demo5.swf)

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
import flash.net.FileReference;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;

if(ExternalInterface.available) {
    //flash.system.Security.allowDomain("localhost");
    ExternalInterface.addCallback("deflate", doDeflate);
    ExternalInterface.addCallback("compress", doCompress);
}

var method:String="deflate";
var b:ByteArray;
function doCompress(_data:String):void {
    method="compress";
    exec(_data);
}

function doDeflate(_data:String):void {
    method="deflate";
    exec(_data);
}

function exec(_data:String):void {
    b=new ByteArray();
    b.writeUTFBytes(_data);
    b.position=0;
    if(method=="compress") {
        b.compress();
    } else if(method=="deflate") {
        b.deflate();
    }
    executed();
}

function executed():void {
    if(ExternalInterface.available) {
        b.position=0;
        var str:String=b.readUTFBytes(b.bytesAvailable);
        ExternalInterface.call("onExec", str);
    }
}
```

My HTML code to embed the swf:

```
<button onclick="doDeflate()">Deflate</button>
<button onclick="doCompress()">Compress</button>
<div id="flashContent">
    <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="1" height="1" id="demo5" align="middle">
        <param name="movie" value="demo5.swf" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
        <param name="play" value="true" />
        <param name="loop" value="true" />
        <param name="wmode" value="window" />
        <param name="scale" value="showall" />
        <param name="menu" value="true" />
        <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
        <param name="salign" value="" />
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />

        <embed src="demo5.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#869ca7"
             width="1" height="1" name="demo5" align="middle"
             play="true" loop="false" quality="high" allowScriptAccess="always"
             type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
             pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
        </embed>
    </object>
</div>
```

and finally the javascript code:

```
function doDeflate() {
    var data="fdg fhnkl,hgltrebdkjlgyu ia43uwriu67ri8m nirugklhvjsd fgvu";
    //DATA CONTAINS DATA TO BE DEFLATED
    thisMovie("demo5").deflate(data);
}

function doCompress() {
    var data="fdg fhnkl,hgltrebdkjlgyu ia43uwriu67ri8m nirugklhvjsd fgvu";
    //DATA CONTAINS DATA TO BE DEFLATED
    thisMovie("demo5").compress(data);
}

function onExec(data) {
    //DATA CONTAINS THE DEFLATED DATA
    alert(data);
}

function thisMovie(movieName) {
    if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
        return window[movieName];
    } else {
        return document[movieName];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm waiting for it. :) Also, is it easy to work with Flash's file handling? I'm guessing in order to get the file you need to use Flash's file dialog box, then compress it and then send it to the server somehow...

Comment: @feketegy, I've added the upload some 32 minutes ago (dunno why the comment I added after that didn't get posted). Anyway, the html in it contains pretty self-explanatory javascript (with comments) so if you don't get anything, don't hesaitate to ask. One catch though: you're going to have to run the html over a http:// domain or add an exception to your flash player (your choice)

Comment: Thanks for this, also, can I pass a file from the <input type="file" />, to the flash? In javascript I have only access to the path of the file and nothing else. So once the file is compressed what do you suggest how to send it to the server?

Comment: ah!! the function needs the contents of the file, not the path. This is because Flash (from the browser) cannot read the file unless it is triggered by user interaction (like click or key down). Alternatively, you could create an entire uploader in Flash. I'll upload such an example soon

Comment: See http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=17_Networking_and_communications_7.html for instructions on how to build an uploader (sorry I can't upload my code because I'm hard pressed for time) Its pretty straightforward

Answer (score 7):

You can make use of [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/). For input, it supports [String/ArrayBuffer/Uint8Array/Buffer](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/file_data.html), but *not* `blob`s, which is what you get from an `<input type="file"/>` with javascript:

> A File object is specific kind of a Blob, and can be used in any context that a Blob can

[(link)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File)

So you'll have to convert the blob/file to e.g. an ArrayBuffer first, e.g. using [`FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer). Note that this function works asynchronously, demanding callback usage. There is also a [FileReaderSync](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReaderSync) available, yet "This interface is only available in workers as it enables synchronous I/O that could potentially block", so I don't see any good in using it.

(**EDIT. I'm not sure but I believe you can skip the blob->ArrayBuffer conversion now and simply zip the File object.**)

This whole approach is specially useful if php's directive [`max_file_uploads`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.max-file-uploads) was set to a small number by your webspace host, for now the only thing you'll have to worry about is [`upload_max_filesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)

For reference, a code sample excerpt follows (using `JQuery`) for putting several files of one `multiple` file input in a zip before submitting:

```
// onclick:
var fileInput = $(':file');
var files = [];
$.each(fileInput[0].files, function(i, file) {
    files.push(file);
});

var zip = new JSZip();
function addFileToZip(n) {
    if(n >= files.length) {
        zippingComplete(zip.generate({type:"blob", compression:"deflate"}));
        return;
    }
    var file = files[n];                    
    var arrayBuffer;
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function() {
        arrayBuffer = this.result;
        zip.file(file.name, arrayBuffer);
        addFileToZip(n + 1);
    };
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
addFileToZip(0);

function zippingComplete(zip) {
    formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('fileZip', zip);
    formData.append("param1", "blah");
    $.ajax({
        data: formData,
        //... etc
```

Server-side-wise, you'll access `$_FILES["fileZip"]`.

Comment: you can skip the blob->ArrayBuffer conversion in version 3+. But for older version (2.6 in my case), your solution was very helpful

Comment: thanks @phil294 this is really helpful, but can i reduce or minify the result file size?i have multiple pdfs and i wanna put them all in a single zip file , so can i reduce the total file size from client side?

Comment: @Immortal The option `compression: 'deflate'` already makes JSZip compress the zip result. You can increase the compression ratio a little more by increasing compression options to level 9, see: https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/generate_async.html

Comment: @phil294 man thanks so much , it works i reduced the file size to the half , can i reduce it much more?

Comment: @Immortal not with JSZip, no... You could try other packages that enable compression algorithms like .tar.xz that would compress all your PDFs combined, not individually, and possibly with an even highter compression ratio. I have no experiences with any such possible libraries though. Also, depending on how you generate the PDFs, you might be able to change their size without compression. For instance, if you use something like html2canvas for PDF generation, they will be rather big because the PDFs are basically images, contrary to text-only pdfs

Answer (score 1):

If for whatever reason you can't get a solution to work in JavaScript for all major browsers, I know of an AS3 compression library here: http://code.google.com/p/ascompress/.

Also, a less cooler option, if your target users are somewhat tech savy why not have them upload a .zip file of the xml? Then on the server side you can unzip and process as needed.

Either way on the server side you'll want to unzip/decompress, which should be easy to google for solutions if you don't already have one in mind.

Comment: thank for the link. Is this solution has a Javascript API? I'm not veri familiar with Flash/Actionscript (I'm just a user). Also, I can't afford to have users zip the XML files beforehand. Unfortunately this must be an automated process, although that would be ideal...

Comment: You can handle all of it in ActionScript, since it has it's own file browser. If you needed it to talk with JavaScript for whatever reason though you can use AS3's ExternalInterface. Pranav's has a nice solution above.

Answer (score 1):

With Silverlight, you can zip files on the client side, and this approach works in all major browsers.  Moreover, you can interact with your Silverlight widget via JavaScript.  Also, if a user needs to upload several files, your Silverlight widget can show a **single** dialog for selecting all the files.  The only drawback is that your clients must install the Silverlight plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Consider reviewing this other [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939791/html-compress-file-upload).  Reading both answers paints a good picture of compression reality.

I'm considering implementing a Silverlight of Flex solution that compresses client side and if the user doesn't want to install it, compress and decompress the file server side.  Will update this post when a solution is found.

Installing the control would be sold to the user as a time saver, which is normally true. For the server, it would be a bandwidth and compression processing saver.

Answer (score 0):

There some javascript library of huffman compression freely available, for example https://github.com/wilkerlucio/huffman_js but I think that your task is impossible because with javascript and html it's not possible to load huge data into the browser or client's memory.

Comment: Hey, thanks, but as I mentioned in the previous comment, I need a solution which works IE7+ and other major browsers. This solution is somewhat an experimental Javascript, which I don't believe can handle large XML files abov 40 - 50 MB.

Comment: @feketegy: It's just a suggestion. You can do it yourself.