# Node.js 1gb csv file upload - Error: Request aborted

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, large-files

I have a problem with large file upload. I have tried to upload smaller files and it's working nicely but when I try to upload larger file (700mb and more) the node.js server is giving me an error:

```
Error: Request aborted at IncomingMessage.onReqAborted (/home/xxx/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/multiparty/index.js:131:17)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at abortIncoming (http.js:1911:11)
    at Socket.serverSocketCloseListener (http.js:1923:5)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at TCP.close (net.js:465:12)
```

Its not even reaching to reading state.

I use

- Google chrome
- express 3.0

I have included

```
app.use(express.bodyParser({limit: '2048mb'}));
```

Also I think I should mention this; after getting the above error, file starts to upload again and fails. Again, there is no issue with smaller files. So my question is how am I able to stream large files effectively with this method, or is there a better method for doing this? Thanks.

Comment: you need to use formidable, just google node formidable. don't use bodyParser, it has been deprecated.

Comment: Since CSV can often be compressed quite will you might find it advantageous to have the browser zip the CSV file before sending it http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/ some people have also used Flash to create file uploaders that compress files http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377268/file-compression-before-upload-on-the-client-side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the following code:

```
var formidable = require('formidable'),
    http = require('http'),
    util = require('util');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if (req.url == '/upload' && req.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {
    // parse a file upload
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
      res.write('Received upload:\n\n');
      res.end(util.inspect(files));
    });

    return;
  }

  // show a file upload form
  res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(
    '<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">'+
    '<input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"><br>'+
    '<input type="submit" value="Upload">'+
    '</form>'
  );
}).listen(80);
```

Source : [felixge/node-formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable#formidable)

Answer (score 2):

At the client side, you need to mention `enctype="multipart/form-data"`