To reduce request sent time when sending multipart/form-data as payload
I am sending a POST request
with headers- { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }
and payload is an object of FormData() class, where i have appended files like-
let formData = new FormData();
    files.forEach((fileObj: any) => {
        formData.append('file', fileObj, fileObj.path);
    })

This request takes 30seconds to be received on server. Is there any way I can reduce this time? Is it possible to achieve this by compressing the file before binding it with formData obj or by JSON.stringfy complete payload and extracting accordingly on backend?

Why does it take 30 seconds on the server? Have you profiled the server software to see why it's spending that much time parsing the form data?

What is the file size?
Also, can you share the server configs for incoming requests

I don't think there's a built-in way. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377268/file-compression-before-upload-on-the-client-side for a library.
