# zip files before upload using javascript

Tags: javascript, image, upload, zip

I am looking for a javascript solution to this problem. [HTML Compress File Upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939791/html-compress-file-upload)

I have found it asked elsewhere in SO, but I prefer a javascript solution because i am using html5 extensively for effects like drag and drop.

The files in question are all images so far. I was hoping not to upload the images 1 by 1.

I have also found this jszip [library](http://stuartk.com/jszip/), but cannot find any examples or documentation stating how to use it for upload purposes.

Comment: Have you tried to compress images? How much do you save?

Comment: i have tried on a folder with 12 jpg images with a total of 2.1M of data. The compressed zip (using normal archive utility in mac os x) is 1.8M. Hence I saved quite significant if I have even more files.

Comment: I cannot rely on users to zip it up before upload. it is part of the features by the way.

Comment: well, for 12 images you've saved about 15%. For 1 image it would be even less. Do you think it worth spending your time? Images *already* use different compression algorithms.

Comment: Let me explain. The users are forced to upload between 20 - 50 pages maximum at any one time. So yes I think it is worth spending some time to do it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17581/discussion-between-kimsia-and-zerkms)