# Streaming Upload/Download

Tags: java, file-upload, playframework, download, netty

I'm trying to create a controller to download and upload files using streaming method, in my case all files are saved in database as a Blob. I read the documentation of Jboss Netty, but i don't think if is the best solution in my case.
Is there a someone who have done something like that before ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to save your files in DB? I've just refined an app which was saving the files in DB because the performance after a few months (when there were a lot of data) was a nightmare..

Comment: I'dont save directly file in DB, firstly i convert it to a byte array, and after i deflate the array using java Zlib and finaly i save the deflated array in DB it's better than to save a file directly in DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://www.lunatech-research.com/playframework-file-upload-blob) for an example of file upload/download. You can add additional processing (compressing...) within your controller.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the problem is how can i upload/download larger files (>3Go) ? if i use the simple way with JPA i'm sure that i'll explode memory, so i'm looking for a streaming method to optimize upload/download using some javascript in client side to split file into chunks and send them to the server in upload case  & to assemble chunks sended by the server in download case
[Something like that](http://kongaraju.blogspot.fr/2012/07/large-file-upload-more-than-1gb-using.html)

Comment: I am not sure if this would be very practical as this means the client's browser would need to load the whole file in memory to compress it. With a 3Gb  file that would make most clients unusable. Consider forcing the clients to zip the files themselves might be a better solution. Read this related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939791/html-compress-file-upload